# While using make command to install touch egg

Tags: linux

I'm trying to install touchegg,
Following is the error i'm getting while trying to use make command in su mode:

```
root@PG04954:/home/esrsank/Downloads/touchegg-1.1# make

g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o touchegg Config.o GestureCollector.o GestureHandler.o 
GestureFactory.o Gesture.o GestureTypeEnum.o GestureDirectionEnum.o 
ActionTypeEnum.o ActionFactory.o MinimizeWindow.o CloseWindow.o 
MaximizeRestoreWindow.o ShowDesktop.o SendKeys.o ChangeDesktop.o 
ResizeWindow.o MoveWindow.o RunCommand.o DragAndDrop.o ChangeViewport.o 
MouseClick.o Scroll.o WindowListener.o Main.o Touchegg.o moc_GestureCollector.o
 moc_GestureHandler.o moc_GestureTypeEnum.o moc_GestureDirectionEnum.o    
moc_ActionTypeEnum.o moc_WindowListener.o moc_Touchegg.o    -
L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lutouch-geis -lX11 -lXtst -lXext -lQtXml -lQtGui 
-lQtCore -lpthread 

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lutouch-geis
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [touchegg] Error 1
```

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It can't find libutouch-geis, either because it isn't installed or because the location of this library isn't in the linker path.

The instructions on [this page](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/CompileSourceCode) suggest installing the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libqt4-dev utouch libgeis-dev libx11-6 libxtst-dev
```

then running:

```
 $ qmake
 $ make
 $ sudo make install
```

Comment: Yeah. seems there is a break in the link,but i installed all the libraries..Anyway Thanks for you reply :)

Comment: Must be the linker path then. Try running make as a standard user, the path might be different. Did you run qmake first?